# Mobile data is not working after missed call

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mobile-data, sony-xperia-u, 2g

I have this strange issue in Sony Xperia U. Currently I am using 6.1.1.B.1.100 bulid ICS 4.0.4. There is no option in mobile network to select 2g or 3g or 2g/3g. All I have is `Use only 3g networks` in my settings. But I managed to select 2g network from the code `*#*4636#*#*` (**Phone info**) and select `GSM only` in `Select prefferred network type`.

But the problem is this when I am using 2g data( to save juice) whenever I get a missed call after that my mobile data is unavailable( I know unlike 3g in 2g you cant use data during voice call but this is after the missed call). This is not happening if I am in 3g and only for missed calls alone.

The only way I am able to use the data again is I have to enable 3g again and change back to 2g.

Is this normal? Any workaround for this? I didnt find this when I am using previous build.

Answer (score -2):

A typical A-GPS-enabled receiver will use a data connection (Internet or other) to contact the assistance server for aGPS information. If it also has functioning autonomous GPS, it may use standalone GPS, which is sometimes slower on time to first fix, but does not depend on the network, and therefore can work beyond network range, and without incurring data usage fees. Some A-GPS devices do not have the option of falling back to standalone or autonomous GPS.

Comment: What does aGPS have to do with the original question?